# Boot directly to Windows instead of Windows Boot Manager

Tags: grub2, windows, uefi, grub-efi

I have installed Ubuntu 16.10 alongside Windows 10, both systems on one physical SSD. Grub has detected both systems, but the problem is, Windows is not booted directly.

I have to choose "Windows Boot Manager" option, then the pc is restarted and Windows booting sequence start.

What I want, is to skip the "restarting" part. I tried adding Windows 10 to grub manually but I am sure I did it wrong.

Any advice how to do it correctly?

Output of `fdisk -l`

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     239616 437651455 437411840 208,6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  499093504 500117503   1024000   500M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  437651456 482492415  44840960  21,4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  482492416 499093503  16601088   7,9G Linux swap
```

I tried adding it manually but I am not sure which options are correct, this was just trial and error

```
set root=(hd0,3)
chainloader +1
```

And this one is for Windows Boot Manager (this one is generated by grub so it works)

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd0,gpt1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  A68D-8D4A
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root A68D-8D4A
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Comment: First of all, your PC doesn't "restart", Grub chainloads the Windows Boot Manager as expected and that's all. Secondly, you need to understand UEFI and stop retrofitting old methods that are applicable to the old Legacy/BIOS only. With UEFI you can boot any installed OS directly from UEFI settings by changing the boot order.

Comment: I know I can change boot order in UEFI but I want grub to start loading windows directly if that's possible. If it uses windows boot manager it show my loading screen (Acer logo) first, and that's unnecesary delay when booting

Comment: Please read and understand this before anything else: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI . Now that you do understand it please use the technologies as they were/are designed instead of retrofitting. For your case you should boot Windows directly from the UEFI boot menu entry for Windows in order to avoid Grub. Doing anything else is overcomplicating something that's so simple and it may have unintended results.

Comment: Ok then, guess I'll just reinstall both systems and choose bios instead of uefi.

Comment: I advise against re-installing both OSes; that's a lot of hassle and creates new opportunities for new things to go wrong. Without knowing *how* the boot to Windows is failing, it's hard to be sure what's wrong; but see my answer below for my initial guess and suggested fixes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what happens when you try booting using the auto-generated Windows entry in the GRUB menu, but my suspicion is that you're running into the following long-standing bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464

If so, there are a couple of relatively simple workarounds:

- Disable Secure Boot. How to do this varies from one computer to another, but it's usually pretty simple once you know how. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) for a few illustrated examples.
- Install rEFInd. My [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) does a better job of launching Windows than GRUB, and so may be helpful. One caveat is that you'll need to jump through some hoops with EFI Secure Boot key installation to get rEFInd to start up with Secure Boot active.

Comment: I'll look into it soon. I wouldn't say it's a bug, for me it's just inconvenient way to boot to windows. On my old Sony notebook with BIOS it showed GRUB where I have option to boot to ubuntu or windows. By choosing windows, It starts booting windows. On my new Acer notebook with UEFI, It shows Acer logo then grub appears with options for ubuntu and windows boot manager, When I choose Windows, it shows acer logo again and starts booting windows. It just looks like restarting. That's what I want to get rid of